# Protractor - Get Attribute Value returning null after after updating chrome version

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, e2e

Get Attribute Value returning null after updating to latest chrome version 91.0.4472.77. Before update it was working fine

```
   selector.getAttribute('value')  => returning null
```

Is there any alternative or solution for this ?

Comment: this question has been asked 6 times in the last week. It's because of the bug in chromedriver v91

Comment: it works fine , with v91do you have any example website ?

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me.
We have written a function for return attributes. Inside that we kept
return browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].value', elem);

getAttribute will continue to work if attribute is part of DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temp workaround that just worked with chrome `91.0.4472.114` on mac

The problem described here is actually a bug in chromedriver https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1205107 so it is not Protractor problem only

While it's being worked on, **you can use chromedriver version 90**. Works like a charm. The latest version available is here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_90.0.4430

You can downgrade chromedriver by running this command

```
webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome 90.0.4430.24
```

Note sometimes you have global, project local and Protractor specific installations of webdriver-manager. The command I gave will install chromedriver globally. In order to install locally you need to find the path to your webdriver-manager and run command like this

```
node ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome 90.0.4430.24
```

And some of you may need to run command in `sudo` mode. Keep it in mind